# Oracle Procedure to Enable/Disable all constraints

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, migration, constraint

I have this nice piece of code:

```
begin
for i in 
(
    select constraint_name, table_name 
    from user_constraints 
    where constraint_type ='R'
    and status = 'ENABLED'
) LOOP
execute immediate 'alter table '||i.table_name||' disable constraint '||i.constraint_name||'';
end loop;
end;
/
```

I'm using if very often for my migration so it would be even better to create a procedure out of if. The procedure should accept one boolean argument (should it enable or disable constraints), but frankly I had never wrote a procedure before. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you put the code in an AUTHID CURRENT_USER package.  You can certainly pass a Boolean, but I think a Varchar2 makes the usage clear.  You should unit test this code, add documentation, formalize the error handling, include instrumentation, and probably modify the reporting method.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Maint AUTHID CURRENT_USER IS

Procedure ToggleConstraints (iNewStatus In Varchar2);

END;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Maint IS

Procedure ToggleConstraints (iNewStatus In Varchar2) Is
Begin
   If (UPPER(iNewStatus) NOT IN ('ENABLED','DISABLED')) Then
      Raise_Application_Error(-20001
         , 'Constraints can only be toggled to ENABLED OR DISABLED.');
   End If;

   For vConstraint In 
   (
       SELECT 'alter table ' || table_name      
         || DECODE(UPPER(iNewStatus), 'DISABLED',' disable',' enable')
         || ' constraint ' || constraint_name As Statement
       FROM user_constraints 
       WHERE constraint_type = 'R' 
       AND status = DECODE(UPPER(iNewStatus),'DISABLED','ENABLED','DISABLED')
   ) Loop
      DBMS_Output.Put_Line(vConstraint.Statement);
      execute immediate vConstraint.Statement;
   End loop;
End;


END;
/

Set serveroutput on size 1000000 format wrapped
EXECUTE Maint.ToggleConstraints(iNewStatus=>'ENABLED');
```

Comment: Additional questions here would be: how to do unit testing? How to formalize error handling? What is instrumentation? How to improve reporting method?

Comment: Each of these points could take a separate white paper to handle even superficially.  The main thing I would recommend is that you read the Oracle Concepts Guide in entirety.  http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/to_pdf?pathname=server.112/e25789.pdf  I'll post a short comment on each of the points so you can learn more after that.

Comment: A list of Unit Testing options for PL/SQL can be found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#PL.2FSQL or you can roll your own. You might want to look at this presentation http://nyoug.org/Presentations/2008/Dec/Feuerstein_Automated%20Testing.pdf.

Comment: Concerning error handling, you need to think about how you will do error handling and then be consistent.  Read Tom Kytes comments at http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4684561825338.

Comment: An instrumentation library for Oracle can be found at http://sourceforge.net/projects/ilo/.    A video introducing ILO can be found at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3MHxqF7Zxj8.

Comment: As far as reporting, you might want to pass back to the caller information about how many objects were changed or which objects rather than just using a DBMS_Output which will only work when serveroutput is turned on.

Answer (score 3):

A very simple procedure for this could look something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_toggle_constraints (in_enable in boolean) is
begin

  if in_enable = false then
    for i in 
    (
      select constraint_name, table_name 
      from user_constraints 
      where constraint_type ='R'
      and status = 'ENABLED'
    ) LOOP
      execute immediate 'alter table '||i.table_name||' disable constraint '||i.constraint_name||'';
    end loop;
  else
    for i in 
    (
      select constraint_name, table_name 
      from user_constraints 
      where constraint_type ='R'
      and status <> 'ENABLED'
    ) LOOP
      execute immediate 'alter table '||i.table_name||' enable constraint '||i.constraint_name||'';
    end loop;
  end if;


--This procedure could be made more elegant, that will be left as an exercise for the reader ;)
end;
```

you might want to read this (document for CREATE PROCEDURE) as well: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6009.htm#SQLRF01309